How do I thread two functions that never terminate?*
I want two thread two functions as I stated. Specifically
public static void playerInput()
{
    while (true)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo pressedKey = Console.ReadKey();
        Doors.input = pressedKey.KeyChar;
        Console.Write('\b');
    }
}

And
public static void openingDoor()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (Doors.input == 'o')
        {
            openDoor();
            Console.WriteLine($"You're now at door {door}");
            input = ' ';
        }
    }
}

opendoor() is a function that just increments a value by 1.
I tried doing
Thread pInput = new Thread(playerInput);

Thread doorOpen = new Thread(openingDoor);

pInput.Start();
doorOpen.Start();

pInput.Join();

doorOpen.Join();

At first it seemed working fine, but after pressing o for like 6 times, it crashes my compiler and gives this error:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

   at System.Timers.Timer.UpdateTimer()
   at System.Timers.Timer.set_Enabled(Boolean value)
   at CSharpShellCore.IDE.Views.ConsoleView.QueueWriteLine(String text)
   at System.Object.CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
   at CSharpShellCore.Console.WriteLineToView(Object o)
   at CSharpShellCore.Console.WriteLine(String n)
   at Doors.Doors.openingDoor()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()

***  ****  ***System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

    at System.Timers.Timer.UpdateTimer() 
    at System.Timers.Timer.set_Enabled(Boolean value) 
    at CSharpShellCore.IDE.Views.ConsoleView.QueueWriteLine(String text) 
    at System.Object.CallSite.Target(Closure, CallSite, Object, String) 
    at CSharpShellCore.Console.WriteLineToView(Object o) 
    at CSharpShellCore.Console.WriteLine(String n) 
    at Doors.Doors.openingDoor() 
    at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()


You should signal the threads to exit, and then Join them. You current thread methods never exit.

"it crashes my compiler and gives this error"  - it looks like a runtime error, not a compilation one.

As Olivier wrote in his answer, multi-threading is the wrong tool for the job here. Imagine, for example, what happens if Console.Write('\b'); gets executed in the middle of Console.WriteLine($"You're now at door {door}");...

Games usually don't use multi-threading. Instead, they have a so called game-loop. It works like this (pseudo-code):
while(true) {
    var userInput = ReadUserInput();
    var newStatus = UpdateGameStatus(previousStatus, userInput, gameTime);
    UpdateUI(newStatus);
}

How this is done exactly depends on whether the game is dynamic or not. By dynamic I mean that objects move or change by themselves without immediate user input. A non dynamic game would only act after a user input.
If the game is dynamic, then you must use a non-blocking user input. You can achieve it like this in a Console application (again pseudo-code):
while(true) {
    while (Console.KeyAvailable) {
        ConsoleKeyInfo pressedKey = Console.ReadKey();
        UpdateUserInputDependentGameStatus(pressedKey);
    }
    UpdateTimeDependentGameStatus();
    UpdateUI();
}

If the game is non dynamic, you can simply do:
while(true) {
    ConsoleKeyInfo pressedKey = Console.ReadKey();
    UpdateUserInputDependentGameStatus(pressedKey);
    UpdateUI();
}

In other words, you must convert your two while (true) loops into one single game loop. You can still use the two methods playerInput() and openingDoor(), but without loops. It is the game loop that will call them repeatedly.
